# How can I write an interface with a static function that returns Self in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, interface, static-methods

I'm trying to write the Kotlin equivalent of what could look like this in Swift:

```
protocol Parseable {
  static func parse(json: JSON) -> Self
}
```

I could not find how to define an interface with a requirement on a static method, nor how to reference to the implementing type in the interface.

Comment: What exactly does `self` mean? Is it the same as `this` in java? If yes, then there is no way to write code such as above, because static methods don't have access to a `this reference`. You can look more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387309/returning-a-class-object-from-static-method)

Comment: I think this is a generic interface using CRTP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Swift, but it looks like you're talking about a ‘self type’ — which represents the type of the class implementing the interface.

Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn't have self types.  (See [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371) for a very long-lasting discussion on the prospects of it being added.)

The usual workaround in Kotlin (and Java) is to make the interface [generic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html), and give the implementing class as a type parameter.  (I don't think there's a specific name for this pattern, but the equivalent in C++ is known as the [curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).)

However, the method in question is static, and so that pattern doesn't apply directly.

What you have there looks like a factory, and there are several ways that could be implemented — I'm not sure which best matches your Swift code, but each one can use generics.  You could have a factory class, with one instance for each type of Parseable that you want to create; in that case, the factory class could have a type parameter.  Alternatively, you might have a singleton factory object, or a companion object, or a top-level factory function; in those cases, the function itself can be generic.

Here's what factory function might look like:

```
fun <P : Parseable> parse(json: JSON): P {
    // Code that returns a value of type P
}
```

(In practice, you'd probably find you'd need access to some of the details of P, which aren't normally available at runtime due to [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure).  But you can work around that by making P [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) — which also needs the function to be [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html).)

Depending on the context, the caller might need to specify the type, e.g.:

```
val result = parse<MyParseable>(json)
```

(The IDE will usually let you know if you need to provide the type, or whether the compiler can infer it.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of static, Kotlin has companion objects which are practically similar.

We can do what looks like static inheritance by extending a class or implementing an interface on a companion object. And there is no self-type, but we can use generics.

```
interface Parseable <T> {
    fun parse(json: Json): T
}

class Foo {
    companion object: Parseable<Foo> {
        override fun parse(json: Json): Foo {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}

fun testParsingFoo(json: Json) {
    Foo.parse(json)
}
```

I'm not versed well in Swift, so let me know if I'm misunderstanding the question. But I think this is the Kotlin equivalent of what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could get behavior similar to a `self` type, which Kotlin doesn't have, is to create an extension function outside the interface with a generic receiver.

```
interface Parseable {
    
}

fun <T: Parseable> T.parse(json: JSON): T {
    // implementation
    return this
}
```

This extension function can be called on anything that implements `Parseable` and will return the instance it was called on, and the compiler will recognize it as its own type, not just Parseable.